# How to install libapt-pkg.so.5.0 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, apt, dynamic-library

I have a dynamic library that I want to use. However, one of its dependencies is not available on my system:

```
$ ldd redacted_name.so | grep 'not found'
        libapt-pkg.so.5.0 => not found
```

I tried installing `libapt-pkg`, and it seemed to work. Here is the output for installing:

```
$ sudo apt install -y libapt-pkg5.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
  apt apt-utils libapt-pkg6.0
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 307 not upgraded.
Need to get 2346 kB of archives.
After this operation, 42.0 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libapt-pkg6.0 amd64 2.0.9 [839 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 apt amd64 2.0.9 [1294 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 apt-utils amd64 2.0.9 [213 kB]
Fetched 2346 kB in 2s (1474 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 54241 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libapt-pkg6.0_2.0.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapt-pkg6.0:amd64 (2.0.9) over (2.0.2) ...
Setting up libapt-pkg6.0:amd64 (2.0.9) ...
(Reading database ... 54241 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/apt_2.0.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apt (2.0.9) over (2.0.2) ...
Setting up apt (2.0.9) ...
Removing obsolete conffile /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal ...
(Reading database ... 54240 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apt-utils_2.0.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apt-utils (2.0.9) over (2.0.2) ...
Setting up apt-utils (2.0.9) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
```

Note that it says no packages were newly installed, and also note that it lists `libapt-pkg6.0` in the output.

However, then I still see that the dependency is not found:

```
$ ldd redacted_name.so | grep 'not found'
        libapt-pkg.so.5.0 => not found
```

Also, when I grep for my installed packages, `libapt-pkg5.0` does not appear, but for some reason `libapt-pkg6.0` *does* appear:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep libapt

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libapt-pkg6.0/focal-updates,now 2.0.9 amd64 [installed]
```

If I try to install `libapt-pkg5.0` again, it fails, mentioning that it is referred to by another package:

```
$ sudo apt install -y libapt-pkg5.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libapt-pkg5.0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libapt-pkg5.0' has no installation candidate
```

How can I correctly install libapt-pkg**5.0** on my Ubuntu 20.04 system?

Comment: You could download it from the Ubuntu 18.04 repository and attempt to install it with gdebi.